# How to fix getting null in password php laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, methods

I am working on login for my website. I worked with this function. But I keep having result = false

```
 public function customer_login(Request $request) {
    $customer_email=$request->customer_email;
    $password=$request->password;
    $result=DB::table('tbl_customer')
                ->where('customer_email',$customer_email)
                ->where('customer_password',$password)
                ->first();
        //dd($password);
        if($result) {
             Session::put('customer_id',$result->customer_id);
            return Redirect::to('/checkout');
        }else{
            return Redirect::to('/login-check');
        }
}
```

I checked the customer_email data as well as password data. the email is correct but the password is null.

edit 1 :

i check what is the content of $request and there is what i found [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwxS0.jpg)

here is my view's html :

```
 <div class="login-form"><!--login form-->
                    <h2>Login to your account</h2>
                    <form action="{{url('/customer_login')}}" method="post">
                        {{csrf_field()}}
                        <input type="email" required="" placeholder="Email" name="customer_email"/>
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password " required="" />
                        <span>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"> 
                            Keep me signed in
                        </span>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
                    </form>
                </div><!--/login form-->
```

Comment: First off, please take a look at laravel's build in authentication! Furthermore you could start debugging this issue by checking the contents of `$request`, if you indeed don't see what you posted as password there, take a look at (and update you question with) your html, from there on we can help you more.

Comment: The best way for [Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#included-authenticating) with Laravel is to use [Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic) .

Comment: @milo526 I checked the contents of $request. password and i can see the password I wrote. i updated the question with the information needed. thank you

Comment: thank you! i will check this documentation

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a space character in the name of password input.
Change your html to this.

```
 <div class="login-form"><!--login form-->
                <h2>Login to your account</h2>
                <form action="{{url('/customer_login')}}" method="post">
                    {{csrf_field()}}
                    <input type="email" required="" placeholder="Email" name="customer_email"/>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required="" />
                    <span>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"> 
                        Keep me signed in
                    </span>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
                </form>
            </div><!--/login form-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the name in the password input, you have one space.

```
name="password "
```